# Spring MVC request mapping not working

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

I want to create simple hello world application with one controller. Plain spring without any classes works, but when I add a controller, change xml files (following step-by-step tutorials), and try to open localhost/project/hello.html, it throws me 404 error.

```
package com.beingjavaguys.controller;  

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  

@Controller  
public class HomeController {  

 @RequestMapping("/hello")  
 public ModelAndView test() {  
  String message = "Welcome to Spring 4.0 !";  
  return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);  
 }  
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.beingjavaguys.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

I tried changing `@RequestMapping` into `("/hello.htm")`, adding request type, adding `@RequestMapping` info the whole class, but nothing works. What's wrong?

Comment: please post your Redirect.jsp.

Comment: Try opening *http://localhost/project/hello.htm*? Change the load on startup for dispatcher to `1`

Comment: <% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %> - That's all there is

Comment: @Octopus opening it displays 404 error, I wrote it at the top of the thread.

Comment: Yes, you said you opened with `.html` extension. Now, just with `.htm`!

Comment: Ah, right :D But both ways don't work. Changing load on startup into 1 doesn't help either.

Comment: try putting just a `/*` in the url-pattern like this `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` for `dispatcher`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableWebMvc` to your configuration to enable MVC-config in java code.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-enable