# Spring MVC with Maven, The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a simple webapp to apply the learnings of spring MVC, the issue occurs while configurating the dispatcher servlet.

I get this message when i click on submit button in index.jsp
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/DemoMVC/add] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
    <input type="submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<!--    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> -->
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.first</groupId>
  <artifactId>DemoMVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DemoMVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>       
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>DemoMVC</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

dispatcher servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.first"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    

    <!-- ... -->

</beans>
```

Controller

```
package com.first;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AddController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add()
    {
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is some issue with Requestmapping annotation, as I tried creating a constructor in the controller and it printing in console.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following changes:

1. Add method attribute in . Example for 'post'

   `<form action="/add" method="post">`
2. In controller either add method type OR use specific mapping annotation:
   `@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)` OR `@PostMapping("/add")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would have to change the name of your dispatcher servlet to xyz-servlet.(here xyz is taken as any name you like but it should be followed by -servlet.)This will help web.xml to map your dispatcher servlet. Also your dispatcher servlet should be in WEB-INF folder.

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>xyz</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xyz</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Also don't forget to add suffix and prefix in your xyz-servlet.xml file

Comment: @Mohammed Athar also don't forget to vote my answer

Comment: Thanks for trying, however the servlet name and location is as what you are recommending, also I found that the controller is working but requestmapping is not working as I created a constructor in controller and the things in controller were printing but the requestmapping seesm to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First I created a constructor in controller to check if controller is working.

```
@Controller
public class AddController 
{
    public AddController() {
        System.out.println("################000");
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String add()
    {
        System.out.println("################12");
        return "welcome.jsp";
    }
}
```

and the console was printing ################000 but did not print ################12. Hence there was an issue in request mapping.

After checking
[Spring MVC request mapping not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834816/spring-mvc-request-mapping-not-working)

**tried implementing <mvc:annotation-driven /> in servlet and it worked**

Answer (score 0):

Ok So if all the things which i told you and others told you aren't working then the problem may be that you have not set the suffix amd prefix in your project.
xyz-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.first"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    

        <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name = "prefix" value = "/webapp/jsp/"/><!--Set the path of where your have stored your view files-->
   <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp"/><!--Set the view resolver type eg. html, jsp-->
  </bean>  
</beans>
```

Now this may solve your issue!!